# Регулярное выражение для получения имени из результата

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пишу игру и тут появилась проблема, мне надо достать имя пользователя из строки, думаю это можно через регулярные выражения сделать. Дана строка:

```
1: Igr7ok:536
```

Где:

- `1:` - место пользователя (число от 1 до 20)
- `Igr7ok` - имя игрока, его и надо достать (любые символы)
- `:536` - результат (любое число)

При помощи регулярного выражения надо получить получить `Igr7ok`, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А язык какой ? во многих языках есть функция split или ее аналоги, делящие строку по заданному разделителю. т.е. она поделит строку точно на место имя и результат

Comment: @Mike Пишу на GDScript, он как Python

Comment: Функция split есть https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_string.html#class-string-split

Comment: @Mike Да есть такая

Comment: Тогда почему не попробовать что-то типа `stroka.split(":")[1].strip_edges()`? Если формат неизменный, незачем задействовать такое тяжёлое вооружение, как регулярки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew думаю можно, позже попробую

Comment: Ну как, сработало?